# Javascript: return a nested promise from a function

Tags: javascript

I'm writing an application in React (react-native actually, but it's not relevant).

I'm using a bluetooth module that perform different actions in the form of chained promises, something like this:

```
  writeData(data) {
    this.manager.startDeviceScan(null, null, (error, device) => {
      if (error) {
        this.store.dispatch({type: "SET_ERROR", payload: error.message})
        return
      }

      if (device.name === 'MyDevice') {
        this.store.dispatch({type: "SET_STATUS", payload: "Device found, stopping device scan...\n"})

        this.manager.stopDeviceScan();

        device.connect().then((device) => {
          this.store.dispatch({type: "SET_STATUS", payload: "Device is connected!\n"})
          return device.discoverAllServicesAndCharacteristics()
        }).then((device) => {
          device.writeCharacteristicWithoutResponseForService(
            data.serviceId,
            data.charId,
            data.dataToWrite
          ).then(res => {
            this.store.dispatch({type: "SET_STATUS", payload: `${data.message}!\n`})

            device.cancelConnection().then(res => {
              this.store.dispatch({type: "SET_STATUS", payload: 'Action dispatched, closing connection\n'})
            }).catch(error => {
              this.store.dispatch({type: "SET_ERROR", payload: error.message})
            })
          }).catch(error => {
            this.store.dispatch({type: "SET_ERROR", payload: error.message})
          })
        }).catch((error) => {
          this.store.dispatch({type: "SET_ERROR", payload: error.message})
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

Now, to have more flexibility in my application I would like to handle errors and success in the local component where I call this function. So, instead of having this function in a separate file and using it in various component like this:

```
  BleApi.writeData({
    serviceId: "ee733136-2de5-4e04-ae81-xxxxxxxxx",
    charId: "cde744c6-2966-4b08-84d2-xxxxxxxxx",
    dataToWrite: btoa(`${index};${program};0`),
    message: "Program has been successfully added.",
  })
```

I would like to return the promise from the connection module, so I can have the then/catch in the local component:

```
device.connect().then((device) => {
  this.store.dispatch({type: "SET_STATUS", payload: "Device is connected!\n"})
  return device.discoverAllServicesAndCharacteristics()
}).then((device) => {
  // this is the function I would like to return:
  return device.writeCharacteristicWithoutResponseForService(
    data.serviceId,
    data.charId,
    data.dataToWrite
  )
```

and then wherever I call this function:

```
  BleApi.writeData({
    serviceId: "ee733136-2de5-4e04-ae81-xxxxxxxxx",
    charId: "cde744c6-2966-4b08-84d2-xxxxxxxxx",
    dataToWrite: btoa(`${index};${program};0`),
    message: "Program has been successfully added.",
  }).then(res => {}).catch(error => {}) // now I can handle the result/errors here
```

but with this code I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`

How can I fix this?

EDIT: error in copying the function (it was BleApi both time), plus I want to clarify something that I forgot: I know that BleApi.writeData returns a promise because that's the functon I'm writing. I want it to return a promise and right now it returns undefined. Sorry for not specifying this before

EDIT 2: I guess I missed another piece of relevant information. In the function `writeData` everything is wrapped around the function `startDeviceScan` of the bluetooth module, and the way I wrote `discoverAllServicesAndCharacteristics` is entirely taken form the documentation of the module: https://polidea.github.io/react-native-ble-plx/

Comment: `Ble.writeData` doesn't return a Promise - what makes you think it did? Since only you know the BLE API you're using, only you can check what that function returns

Comment: Ble.writeData is the function that I'm writing. See the updated question!

Comment: yeah, `writeData` doesn't return anything

Comment: And that's the problem I'm trying to solve. How can I make it returns the function "device.writeCharacteristicWithoutResponseForService" ?

Comment: read the answer

Answer (score 2):

I assume `Ble.writeData`/`BleApi.writeData` is the function where your `device.connect()` code is located? If so, the problem is that you're not returning the promise chain. It's hard to give you a solid answer without more context for the code you've provided, but it would be something like:

```
writeData() {
    return device.connect()
    .then((device) => {
      this.store.dispatch({type: "SET_STATUS", payload: "Device is connected!\n"})
      return device.discoverAllServicesAndCharacteristics();
    })
    .then((device) => {
      return device.writeCharacteristicWithoutResponseForService(
        data.serviceId,
        data.charId,
        data.dataToWrite
      );
    });
}
```

(I'm using method syntax there, assuming this is within an object literal or a class.)

...except I suspect you meant for this line:

```
return device.discoverAllServicesAndCharacteristics();
```

to be

```
return device.discoverAllServicesAndCharacteristics().then(() => device);
```

...since your next `then` handler expects to get `device`. If so, then:

```
writeData() {
    return device.connect()
    .then((device) => {
      this.store.dispatch({type: "SET_STATUS", payload: "Device is connected!\n"})
      return device.discoverAllServicesAndCharacteristics().then(() => device);
    })
    .then((device) => {
      return device.writeCharacteristicWithoutResponseForService(
        data.serviceId,
        data.charId,
        data.dataToWrite
      );
    });
}
```

---

But note that since you're transpiling with React Native, you can use an `async` function so you can write your logical flow with standard flow control constructs rather than `.then` and `.catch` handlers:

```
async writeData() {
    const device = await device.connect();
    this.store.dispatch({type: "SET_STATUS", payload: "Device is connected!\n"})
    await device.discoverAllServicesAndCharacteristics();
    return device.writeCharacteristicWithoutResponseForService(
        data.serviceId,
        data.charId,
        data.dataToWrite
    );
}
```